# C# cut area from image

Tags: c#, pointers, image-processing

I'm trying to implement a cropping method myself,using the unsafe code and pointer to speed up the whole process.

This is my code:

```
private unsafe void Cut(Bitmap bmp, Rectangle r) {

Bitmap result = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height, bmp.PixelFormat);
BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
BitmapData bmData2 = result.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width, result.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, result.PixelFormat);
IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
int stride = bmData.Stride;
int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;


int x = r.X;
int y = r.Y;
int width = r.Width;
int height = r.Height;

for (; y < height; y++) {
 byte * p = (byte * ) scan0.ToPointer();
 p += y * stride;
 byte * p2 = (byte * ) scan02.ToPointer();
 p2 += y * stride2;

 for (; x < width; x++) {

  p2[0] = p[0];
  p2[1] = p[1];
  p2[2] = p[2];
  p2[3]=p[3];
  p += 4;
  p2 += 4;

 }

}

result.Save("a.png");
```

}

And the call to this method:

```
       Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\itapi\Desktop\1.png");
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(200, 500, 300, 450);
        Cut(b, r);
```

When i run the code,i just get a black rectangle as result...not the pixels i wanted to copy from the intial image.

**The image from the example above is  in`32bpprgb` format**
I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong..i'll appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the result, you chose "System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly"   I think you want ReadWrite or WriteOnly.

When I ran through debugger, this statement: for (; y < height; y++)  condition failed immediately on my rather large image.  So your loop logic is incorrect for running through the lines...   Use a debugger :)

*EDIT*  I ran it through the debugger, and your Y and X logic is wrong.  I did a quick fix on the Y logic, and got it too crop.  You'll have to do something similar to the X to get the correct crop point.
Try this, it cropped and saved a file:

```
        int x = r.X;
        int y = r.Y;
        int width = r.Width;
        int height = r.Height;
        int newY = 0; 
        for (y = r.Y; y < height+r.Y; y++) //For each line in the old image
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;
            byte* p2 = (byte*)scan02.ToPointer();
            p2 += newY * stride2;

            for (x=r.X; x < width+r.X; x++)
            {

                p2[0] = p[0];
                p2[1] = p[1];
                p2[2] = p[2];
                p2[3] = p[3];
                p += 4;
                p2 += 4;

            }
            newY++;
        }

        result.Save("\\a.png");
```

Comment: you pointed to somthing right..but it didn't solved the problem:) not yet. i see the same black image.

Comment: Note that I made as small changes as possible to your code.  I didn't rewrite it for you, just made it work for Y, it crops X in the wrong spot, but you can figure that out.......